# How to be able to access data files in all install and distribution cases with setuptools?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, packaging, pkg-resources

I'm kind of lost in all the locations you can add data files.
First, there is the `MANIFEST.in` file. As I understand, this is only to specify source files to be included in "source distribution".
Then, there is the `data_files` argument to `setup()` function, where you list files that should be installed, but it's from the root (either `/`, either `~user/.local`). And finally, there is `package_data` that pretends to do what I want... But on a bdist, I don't see any difference with `data_files`

I have a data file, say "default_conf.cfg".

my `MANIFEST.in` contains :

```
include default_conf.cfg
```

and my `setup.py` :

```
setup(
  # ...
  package_data={
    '': ['default_conf.cfg'],
  }
)
```

When I do a `./setup.py sdist`, the file is included, same with `./setup.py bdist` (as expected)

However, if I try to install as editable package (`pip install --user -e .`), I can't access it with `pkg_resources.resource_string(__name__, 'default_conf.cfg')`

What am I missing to be able to access it from any kind on distribution/install ?

(The documentation is quite verbose, and information are dispersed across several pages so it's easy to miss something.)

## **EDIT**

I put my data file as a subdir of my module and it seems to be better :

```
my_pkg/
|-my_pkg/
| |-__init__.py
| |-data/
| | |-default_conf.cfg
| 
|-setup.py
```

setup.py :

```
setup(
  # ...
  package_data={
    'my_module': ['data/default_conf.cfg'],
  }
)
```

However, when I try to `pip install --user -e .`, the content of the .egg-link is `/.../my_pkg/build/lib` instead of `/.../my_pkg`, then of course, it is not live-editable... Why does setuptools use this path ?

Comment: What is `pkg_resource`?

Comment: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html

The "standard way" to access resources (normally)

Comment: well, there was a copy-paste typo, now, I corrected the call to `resource_string`

Comment: Your `package_data` is now correct, so it should work. First of all, try cleaning up: `pip uninstall -y mypkg`, delete `build` and `mypkg.egg-info` dirs in the project dir, then rerun `pip install --editable .`. If this doesn't help, check whether you have an unnecessary `__init__.py` in your project dir and remove it.

Comment: what do you mean by "unnecessary `__init__.py" ? because I effectively have an empty `__init__.py` because I have only submodule

Comment: btw, I created another question to complete this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51306780/when-does-setuptools-install-editable-link-to-my-module-build-lib-andwhen

Comment: I meant, if the error is not resolved by clean rebuild, check if you have an `__init__.py` file in the same dir your `setup.py` is, often it's a source for errors where the `build` dir is added to python path. The project structure you've shown in the post looks good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174887/discussion-between-hl037-and-hoefling).

Answer (score 0):

The edit actually answers the question. The install editable problem was caused by a py2to3 step that was by default in my setup.py template.